# Convert Decimal To String C#

Tags: c#, string, .net-core, type-conversion, decimal

How can i convert decimal to string **without rounding** and with specific format?

It is my value;

```
var price = 4569.996M;
```

I want to this result `result = "4.569,99"` . I can check to culture for seperators like this

```
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
```

I try some codes

```
var result = price.ToString("#,##0.##", CustomCulture);
//when you try this result = "4.570"

var result = Convert.ToDecimal(price).ToString("#,#.#########", customCulture);
//when you try this result = "4.569,996"

var result = price.ToString("N");
//when you try this result = "4,570.00"

 var result = price.ToString("N", customCulture);
 //when you try this result = "4.569,996"
```

My value can be any value. I just want to seperate  with specific format and seperate two digit after comma and not rounding when convert to string.

Comment: "4.569,99" *is* rounding - it's rounding down rather than using Banker's Rounding or rounding away from zero, but it's still rounding. If that's what you mean, please be specific about it.

Comment: (You might want to multiply by 100, call `Truncate`, then divide by 100 again, then format... but I can't really tell while the question is unclear.)

Comment: @gunr2171 thank you! It is fix my problem.
`var result  = (Math.Truncate(price * 100) / 100).ToString("N2",customCulture.NumberFormat);`
@JonSkeet thank you too, i'll try to make my questions more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having unwanted digits after the decimal point you have to round the value, the question is *how* to round it. In your case it seems that you want to *truncate* (`4569.996` -> `4569.99`), i.e. round *to zero*:

```
  var price = 4569.996M;

  string result = $"{Math.Round(price, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero)}";
```

Or

```
  string result = Math.Round(price, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero).ToString();
```